# lenovo e50 and external graphics card

Tags: pci-express, display-adapter, lenovo-desktop-computer

I have a very cheap desktop PC that a friend of mine bought.  Its a Lenovo e50.  However we need dual outputs so I was gonna install a PCI graphics card.  So I've bought a Sparkle Geforce 210.

However I've put the card in, and it just refuses to output to it at all.  I update the BIOS option 'Video Output' to 'PEG' which is PCI Express, and nothing. I save and restart, and move the VGA cable over to the external card, and I get nothing.

I thought that perhaps the new card was just faulty, so I got a replacement, and still the same thing.

It doesn't even recognise any new device in windows device manager.  I'm at a loss, it should be such a simple thing to do, but yet I'm getting nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the Machine Type Model of this computer? It might pay to punch it into the [Lenovo Support](http://suppport.lenovo.com) website to check the exact specifications of the machine as they often have very little PSU overhead and you might be pushing the max power output of the PSU.

That being said, in the Hardware Maintenance Manual there is a list of compatible GFX cards, assuming you have a capable PSU.

Below is a list of compatible graphics cards for the general E50-00 model:

```
GFX Card                                 FRU
--------                                 ---
MSI@Geforce GT630@2G/A/DVI/DP Graphics   11-201671
MSI@Geforce GT630@2G/B/DVI/DP Graphics   11-202534
Mckey DVI-VGA adapter                    31-503273
LX DVI-VGA adapter(R)                    31-038625
MSI@R5 235@512M/A/DB/HVGA                11-202541
BLD@R5 235@512M/A/DB/HVGA                11-202543
BITLAND@R5 235@1G/A/DB/H Graphics        11-202403
MSI@R5 235@1G/A/DB/H Graphics            11-202404
```